# Angular 4 - Interaction Between Non-related Components

Tags: angular

I have a working system where I can define menu items from my control panel and fetch them to multiple places. What I want to add as an extra feature is to refresh the menus (e.g. at sidebar), when I create a new menu item.

Simply, I want to run `getMenu` function defined in my `SidebarComponent`, after `addMenuItem` function in my `MenuComponent` is run.

So far, I have come to this, based on a **Shared Service** suggestion, but it's not working:

MenuService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
    sidebarRefresh: Function;

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    create(): void {
        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data);
    }
}
```

MenuComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from './menu.service';

@Component()

export class MenusComponent {
    constructor(
        private menuService: MenuService,
    ) { }

    addMenuItem(): void {
        this.menuService.create(data);

        this.menuService.sidebarRefresh();
    }
```

SidebarComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Menu } from '../menu/menu';
import { MenuService } from '../menu/menu.service';

@Component()

export class SidebarComponent {
    menus: Menu[];

    constructor(
        private menuService: MenuService
    ) {
        this.menuService.sidebarRefresh= this.getMenu;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getMenu();
    }

    getMenu() {
        this.menuService.getSidebarMenu()
            .subscribe(
                menus => this.menus = menus,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you provide this service? What is `getSidebarMenu()` ? What does `sidebarRefresh` function looks like? Please add all the relevant info.

Comment: My guess is that it would work fine if you relaced `= this.getMenu` by `= () => this.getMenu()`. But it would be much cleaner to emit an event from an Observable in the service after the HTTP call is create() has succeeded, and to subscribe to this Observable in the component.

Comment: You are a life saver @JB Nizet

Comment: You should post your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work fine if you relaced

```
... = this.getMenu;
```

by

```
... = () => this.getMenu();
```

But it would be much cleaner to emit an event from an Observable in the service after the HTTP call in create() has succeeded, and to subscribe to this Observable in the component.

Note that your current solution gets the new menu immediately after you've sent the request to create a new one. So the two requests will probably be handled in parallel by your server, which could lead to a race condition.

Comment: Thank you @JB Nizet, I put the trigger inside **then** property.